# [SQL]Как улучшить этот запрос и сделать его выдачу правильной

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

Задача: необходимо показать сколько мальчиков и девочек получили ту или иную оценку.

Был написан "корявый" запрос под задачу:

```
SELECT r.mark, 
COUNT(r.mark), 
 (SELECT COUNT(r1.mark) FROM results r1 
  JOIN users u1 ON (r1.id_user = u1.id AND r1.ex_mode = 'tmOlympDiagnostic' 
  AND u1.gender = 'Ж'))
FROM results r
JOIN users u ON (r.id_user = u.id AND r.ex_mode = 'tmOlympDiagnostic' AND u.gender = 'М')   
GROUP BY r.mark
ORDER BY r.mark desc;
```

Вывод:

```
    Mark | BoysMarksCount | GirlsMarksCount
---------+----------------+----------------
      5  |        8       |         2
      4  |        1       |         2
      3  |        1       |         2
      2  |        2       |         2
      1  |        1       |         2
---------+----------------+----------------
```

По мальчикам статистику сделать было не трудно, но вот для девочек не знаю как правильно оформить запрос, чтобы третьим столбцом показывало сколько каждой оценки получили девочки, потому что сейчас третий столбец несгруппирован по полю                                 "Mark" и в итоге, имея результаты по диагностики только от двух девочек, в каждом столбце выводит 2 шт. для каждой оценки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT r.mark mark
     , COUNT(r.mark) total
     , SUM(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'М' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) male
     , SUM(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'Ж' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) female
FROM results r
JOIN users u 
  ON r.id_user = u.id
WHERE r.ex_mode = 'tmOlympDiagnostic'
GROUP BY r.mark
ORDER BY r.mark DESC;
```

Comment: Гуру, большое спасибо Вам!

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю выражение `SUM(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'М' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. Правильно ли что, когда после группировки по полю r.marks (вот он вывел все оценки с дубликатами), в функцию SUM, проходясь по сгруппированной выдаче оценок, прибавляется 1, если пол совпал, и 0, если нет?

Comment: Ну если очень грубо, то да.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Не подскажите, как в этом же запросе сделать выдачу в процентах (сколько всего, сколько по мальчикам и сколько по девочкам)?

Comment: Я нашел решение в виде вызова другой функции в запросе, которая возвращает максимальное количество оценок; `ROUND((COUNT(r.mark)::float / get_total_marks()) * 100)`.
Но, может, есть более лаконичный способ справиться в том запросе с примененной группировкой по r.marks?